# css everything on same line

Tags: css

I would like to know what is the easiest way to keep everything in the same line?
all of my things are coming on top of each other

I put my 5 images in the same div but they still came on top of each other

Thanks!

Comment: Code? Link? We aren't psychic.

Answer (score 16):

put a div around "everything" that should be on one line and give that div the following css:

```
everythingOnOneLine {
 white-space: nowrap;
}

everythingOnOneLine * {
 display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean

```
div img {
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the float style of your images to left:

```
<img style="float:left" src="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set `display: inline-block` you can use the best from `inline`-level and `block`-level elements.

This means: Everything in one line but with the possibility to set a `width` or a `height`. Works on all elements like list entries or `div` elements. Not only images.