# CSS - objects aren't in one row

Tags: html, css

I want to have these objects in one row

[image]

My HTML code looks like this:

```
    <input type="button" class="formreturn" value="Copy Url" onclick="Copy();" />
    <label><input type="text" class="txtfilename" id="op-text-filename" placeholder="type file name"/>.txt</label>
    <button type="button" class="formreturn" onclick="saveURLtoTXTfile();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>.TXT</button>  
    <button class="excelsubmit" onclick="exportData()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>.CSV</button>
    <button id="btnExport" class="excelsubmit" onclick="fnExcelReport();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>.XLS </button>
```

and CSS

```
 .formreturn {
font-weight:700;
text-decoration: none;
display:inline-block;
color:black;
background:#c6e2f2;
padding: 9px;
border-radius: 3px;
 }

 .copyurltext {
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 30px;
}

.txtfilename {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
}

.excelsubmit {
font-weight:700;
float: right;
padding: 8px;
background:#c6e2f2;
}
```

If I place the `float:left` in my `formreturn`, then everything is fine, but the order is wrong, as the .txt button goes next to the "Copy Url" button. I want to have the order as you see below, but with everything lined up properly.

I tried something like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/A9Ap7/1/

codeproject.com/Questions/5280800/How-do-I-put-everything-in-one-line

and here

[css everything on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934341/css-everything-on-same-line)

but it didn't work for me

How can I fix this?

Comment: but I don't see enough details in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div classs="btns-left">
        <input type="button" class="formreturn" value="Copy Url" onclick="Copy();" />
        <label><input type="text" class="txtfilename" id="op-text-filename" placeholder="type file name"/>.txt</label>
        <button type="button" class="formreturn" onclick="saveURLtoTXTfile();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>.TXT</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="btns-right"> 
        <button class="excelsubmit" onclick="exportData()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>.CSV</button>
        <button id="btnExport" class="excelsubmit" onclick="fnExcelReport();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>.XLS </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.btns-left,
.btns-right {
  display: flex;
}
```

Also, you can use properties for align elements by horizontal axis, as an example `align-items: flex-start`.

2. Or:
   `float: left;` for btns-left and `float: right;` for btns-right and `display: inline-block;` for every element without `display: flex;` anywhere.
3. Also, can try, float for every element without any wrappers (left properties for left side, right ones for right side)
4. Grid layout, but it's more complicated. The best solution is applying flexbox layout for positioning elements. Better avoid floats, cause it might voke some troubles with clearing flow in future.

Comment: Hi Sir, I have accepted your correction because it was close. For full success I had to apply:

.export {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.export-left {
    display: flex;
}
.export-right {
    margin-left: auto;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to give all elements a `display: inline-block` for starters (so, the button input, label and three buttons), `float: left` is not recommended and bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You want it all to be next to each other? Maybe start using css grid, it's useful for making things in line.

Then there's always the option of setting all these things in a navigation bar, so it's always at the top of your screen in line.

Perhaps try and create a container that holds all the buttons in place?